# Error try to access profile through .net code on sabre ProfileReadRQ

Tags: api, sabre

When we try to access profile through code we are getting message as below, please advice

The error is:

```
There was an error in serializing one of the headers in message
EPS_ProfileReadRQRequest: 'Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
```

> error CS0030: Cannot convert type  'CRM.ProfileReadRQ.BusinessSystemIdentityInfoSynchronizationCriterionTypeExcludeCombination' to 'CRM.ProfileReadRQ.BusinessSystemIdentityInfoSynchronizationCriterionTypeIncludeCombination'
>   error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'CRM.ProfileReadRQ.BusinessSystemIdentityInfoSynchronizationCriterionTypeIncludeCombination' to 'CRM.ProfileReadRQ.BusinessSystemIdentityInfoSynchronizationCriterionTypeExcludeCombination'

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the serializer doesn't know what type to cast to since the types that throw the error can be of more than one type. I think that simplifies the XML but it makes the WSDL/.NET stuff more complicated. I'm probably not saying that perfectly accurately but that's the gist of it, at least as I understand it.

You can go into your reference.cs file and remove the serialization for those offending fields and try again. I've done this in the past with some success. If/when you update the API version with a new WSDL file you'll have to remember to do it again, though, so it's not a perfect solution. I've got a sample of what I removed from my reference.cs file to get one of the profile APIs below, hopefully it's helpful.

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.3056.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.sabre.com/eps/schemas")]
public partial class BusinessSystemIdentityInfoSynchronizationCriterionType {

    private BusinessSystemIdentityInfoSynchronizationCriterionTypeExcludeCombination[] itemsField;

    private ItemsChoiceType1[] itemsElementNameField;

    //remarked this out 12/24/18 - these include/exclude combinations do not serialize correctly for some reason
    /// <remarks/>
    //[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ExcludeCombination", typeof(BusinessSystemIdentityInfoSynchronizationCriterionTypeExcludeCombination))]
    //[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("IncludeCombination", typeof(BusinessSystemIdentityInfoSynchronizationCriterionTypeIncludeCombination))]
    //[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
    //public BusinessSystemIdentityInfoSynchronizationCriterionTypeExcludeCombination[] Items {
    //    get {
    //        return this.itemsField;
    //    }
    //    set {
    //        this.itemsField = value;
    //    }
    //}

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public ItemsChoiceType1[] ItemsElementName {
        get {
            return this.itemsElementNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsElementNameField = value;
        }
    }
}
```